# Get progress of readBytes in android

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I've already seen

> [Is it possible to check progress of URLconnection.getInputStream()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161514/is-it-possible-to-check-progress-of-urlconnection-getinputstream)
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120451/5437621

I'm using the following code to download a file from internet:

```
try {
    InputStream is = new URL(pdfUrl).openStream();
    byte[] pdfData = readBytes(is);
    return pdfData;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}

public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Is there any method I can get the progress of the file being downloaded ?

**The answers I have seen are using a `while` loop but I don't understand how to use it in this case.**

**EDIT:**

I'm using this in AsyncTask:

```
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... url) {
        pdfUrl = url[0];

        try {
            InputStream is = new URL(pdfUrl).openStream();
            DownloadBytes downloadData = readBytes(is);
            byte[] pdfData = downloadData.getBytes();
            progress = downloadData.getProgress();
            return pdfData;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

How can I adjust `publishProgress()` in this method ?

Comment: That would be in your implementation of `readBytes()`, which your question does not show. If you switch to a more modern HTTP client API, you can use interceptors with OkHttp to monitor download progress.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry I missed, I've updated the question and added the code for `readBytes()`

Comment: Um, well, you already have the `while` loop. It is in your `readBytes()` method. In there, you can keep track of how much you have read, and you can use the `getContentLength()` method show in the answers to your first linked-to question to determine how big the overall download should be.

Comment: @CommonsWare please check my updated question. I want to know how can I use `publishProgress()` ?

Comment: Um, well, if `readBytes()` is an `AsyncTask`, you could post some sort of `DownloadEvent` to `publishProgress()`, where each event has the total bytes to be downloaded along with the sum of what has been downloaded so far. Your `onProgressUpdate()` would then use that information to update your UI.

Comment: @CommonsWare hey I still need some help. is there any way i can contact you ? (if you can help)

Comment: I offer office hours chats and other services via [the Warescription](https://commonsware.com/warescription).